# Using nondimensionalization to solve an ode in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations, stiffness

I am trying to solve an ode that uses some extremely large numbers and some extremely small numbers, namely

$$
e = 1.6\times 10^{-19}\\
E = 10^6\\
\tau = 6\times 10^{-24}\\
m = 9.1\times 10^{-31}\\
c = 3\times10^8\\
$$

I introduced some dimensionless constants, one in particular being
$$
\varepsilon = \frac{\tau e}{cm} E \approx 4\times10^{-15}
$$

MATLAB's ode45, ode15s, and ode23s cannot handle these numbers. Am I allowed to just set $\varepsilon = 10$? That number produces a pleasant graph with  a nice solution, but I am not sure how to go from an $\varepsilon = 10$ world back to the original world.

Comment: With constants like these, you may just want to use higher precision arithmetic and call it a day. [This example shows how you'd use Julia's DifferentialEquations.jl](https://tutorials.juliadiffeq.org/html/type_handling/01-number_types.html) to use arbitrary precision Bigfloats or DoubleFloat (128-bit floats) which would handle these numbers just fine.